# Обмен файлами на сайте php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

На уже рабочем сайте работающем на php/mysql/javascript нужно реализовать обмен текстовыми файлами, с общий каталог и быстрым поиском по уже загруженым файлам.Прошу подсказать в каком направлении нужно двигаться, если чесно я не совсем понимаю всю концепцию того как реализуеться файлообменник. Загружаем файл через ajax регистрируя его имя и id в БД?но как то реализовать его выгрузку.Прошу от вас не готового кода, а поделиться личным опытом решения подобного рода задач

Comment: если речь о текстовых файлах то проще всего их хранить в БД. то есть задача сводится к банальнейшей гостевой книге

Comment: *если речь о текстовых файлах то проще всего их хранить в БД.* Если речь идёт о коротких текстовых файлах (максимум пара килограмм) - согласен. А если это "Война и мир" с комментариями - то лучше поискать иные средства.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я против Вашего плага. Разве что до 255 символов то хорошо, а так база данных сделана не для этого. Создайте таблицу с информацией о файле( храня название файла и о нем информацию( если нужно) и с помощью запроса ищите файл

Comment: @Node_pro ну то есть текст этого вопроса уже нельзя в базе хранить, только файле?  А мой самый популярный ответ, который раз в 30 больше назначенного вами лимита - так и вообще наверное на ленту сбрасывать?

Comment: Вот же специалистов набежало. причем как поиск делать по зоопарку файлов - никто не напишет. Зато все о базе данных, бедняжке, заботятся.

Comment: А те кто придумал blob-поля, они вообще наверно про файлы не слышали. Сидят в своей базе данных и ничего не видят больше, ага.

Comment: Да, лучше всего хранить файлы в БД. В некоторых БД даже есть поддержка разных типов файлов, то есть позволит вам искать по содержимому файла. Ну и плюсом идут все плюшки БД - транзакции, репликация, индексы и тд.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, решил попробовать хранить файлы в БД. Так как да, формат будет только текстовый, без комментариев.